# mui date picker, suddenly disabled when in bootstrap modal, but can be typed when outside modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

When editing from button pencil using Material UI v.5.14.6 date picker in mobile mode, it is suddenly disabled when in bootstrap modal, but can be typed when outside modal.

```
import {  Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

<Modal>
<DatePicker
      label="For mobile"
      value={value}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />} // can't type.
     />
</Modal>
```

I hope I can still type even in a bootstrap modal.